# firebase email verification issue that keeps alerting an error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, email-verification

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with the following code.  It triggers an alert when there is an error but seems to always trigger the email is not verified alert.

```js
var userEmail = document.getElementById('userEmail');
var userPw = document.getElementById('userPw');
var btnLogin = document.getElementById('btnLogin');

    btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {
        var email = userEmail.value;
        var password = userPw.value;

        var auth = firebase.auth();

        var promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

        promise.catch(function(error){
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            $.tips(errorMessage, 5000);
            console.log(errorMessage + " Code:" + errorCode);
        });

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
        if(firebaseUser){
            var email = userEmail.value;
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => { 
                  if (user.isEmailVerified) {
                    console.log('Email is verified');
                    console.log(firebaseUser);
                    window.location.href = './main.html';  
                  }
                  else {
                      $.tips("Email is not verified!", 5000);
                      console.log("Email is not verified!");
                  }
            });      
        }
        else {
            console.log('not logged in');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see where you are sending out the verification email to the user. Where are you calling `sendEmailVerification()`, as found in the documentation? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#sendEmailVerification

Comment: Nvm, I figured it out just changed the else statement into an else if statement specifically checking if the user is not verified.